# Generar estructura de ADN con HTML Y CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html5, css3

Cómo crear una estructura de ADN mediante `html` `CSS` que al mismo tiempo este en movimiento, como la siguiente imagen: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero utilizando HTML CSS y si es necesario jQuery y este vertical mente la estructura?

Cuento con el el siguiente `código` html pero seria que quedara un poco mas parecido al de la `img`

```css
z-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

```html
<body  >  
 <h1><span class="blue">1</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">1</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">2</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">2</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">3</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">3</span></h1>
 <h1><span class="blue">4</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">4</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">4</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">5</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">6</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">6</span></h1>
 <h1><span class="blue">7</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">7</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">8</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">8</span></h1>
  
 <h1><span class="blue">9</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">9</span></h1>
     
    

</body>
```

Comment: Te sirvió de algo mi respuesta @Soldier ?

Comment: Si gracias @RuslanLópez :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener algo similar de la siguiente manera:

1. Usa la propiedad `rotateY`, que te recibe valores de 0 a 360°, esto te permitirá rotar el componente html en el eje vertical
2. Gira el div para que quede acostado como en el ejemplo
3. Crea una animación usando un bloque `@keyframes` donde modifique la propiedad del punto 1
4. para cada hijo agrega un retraso diferente en un intervalo progresivo mediante la propiedad `animation-delay`

```css
 /* WebKit and Opera browsers */

 @-webkit-keyframes spinner {
   from {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
   to {
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
   }
 }

 /* all other browsers */

 @keyframes spinner {
   from {
     -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
     transform: rotateY(0deg);
   }
   to {
     -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg);
     transform: rotateY(-360deg);
   }
 }

 #stage {
   margin: 1em auto;
   -webkit-perspective: 1400px;
   -moz-perspective: 1400px;
   -ms-perspective: 1400px;
   perspective: 1400px;
   
   /* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 }

 #spinner *{
   -webkit-animation-name: spinner;
   -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
   -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
   animation-name: spinner;
   
   animation-timing-function: linear;
   animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   animation-duration: 6s;
   -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
 }

#spinner *:nth-child(1) { 
  animation-delay: -1.9s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(2) { 
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(3) { 
  animation-delay: -2.3s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(4) { 
  animation-delay: -2.4s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(5) { 
  animation-delay: -2.6s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(6) { 
  animation-delay: -2.8s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(7) { 
  animation-delay: -3.0s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(8) { 
  animation-delay: -3.2s;
}

#spinner *:nth-child(9) { 
  animation-delay: -3.4s;
}

 #spinner:hover {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation-play-state: paused;
 }

span.grey {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.green {
  background: #5EA226;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.blue {
  background: #5178D0;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}

span.pink {
  background: #EF0BD8;
  border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
```

```html
<div style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);">
<div id="stage">
  <div id="spinner" style="text-align: center; color: #fff;">
    <h1><span class="blue">1</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">1</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">2</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">2</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">3</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">3</span></h1>
    <h1><span class="blue">4</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">4</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">4</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">5</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">6</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">6</span></h1>
    <h1><span class="blue">7</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">7</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">8</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">8</span></h1>

    <h1><span class="blue">9</span><span>_____________ </span><span class="pink">9</span></h1>

  </div>
</div>
```